# LinearLayouts in CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I would like to have a CardView with few (vertical LinearLayouts in there)- However, I can not see it the views in AS (design mode) and in my app are all the view in one line. I want every TextView in just one line (so four lines in cardview)

my xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todayTempMin"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="8 °C"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todayWind"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="4 km/h"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todayPressure"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="1026 mbar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todayHumidity"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="80%"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the width to match_parent?

Comment: post screenshots what does it look like now and a drawing what you are trying to achieve

Comment: problem was with `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the cardView as parent, and the LinearLayout inside.

Answer (score 2):

CardView should have only one direct child.